# How do I make canvas_create_oval a button? Where I can click on it and a command will be executed Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

How do I make this a button.

```
circle=scanvas.create_oval(440,220,310,90, activeoutline="black",outline="white", fill="purple", width="5")
```

Comment: From your question as it is now, no one can understand what you want to the tiniest bit. Edit it, explain it, and some code you tried with

Comment: akshay gave me the perfect answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a drawn element on the canvas behave like a button by listening to the click event on the canvas and tagging it to the element using the tag_bind method as shown in the code below.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, messagebox

 top = Tk()

 def callback(event):
    messagebox.showinfo('Hello World','Hello Python')

 canvas = Canvas(top,bg="white",height=250,width=250)
 circle = canvas.create_oval(10,10,80,80,outline="black",fill="red")

 canvas.tag_bind(circle,"<Button-1>",callback)

 canvas.pack()
 top.mainloop()
```

The `<Button-1>` listens to a mouse press. You can learn more about the different events [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: sorry I've worded it badly, how do I make this oval an interactive button, in which when I click it, it will execute a command

Comment: @cj5yens ok edited to answer your question

Comment: @cj5yens please accept the answer if it worked for you